# File Stream - ValueError: embedded null byte

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to download a .png image via HTTP requests and upload it via HTTP to another location. My objective is to avoid saving the file on the disk so it's processed in-memory.

I have the code below:

1. Download the file and convert it into a byte array:

```py
resp = requests.get(
    'http://www.personal.psu.edu/crd5112/photos/PNG%20Example.png',
    stream=True)

img = BytesIO(resp.content)
```

2. Upload the file to a remote HTTP repository

```
data=open(img.getvalue()).read()

r = requests.post(url=url, data=data, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'user'))
```

I'm getting a ValueError exception "embedded null byte" when reading the byte array.

If I save the file onto the disk and load it as below, then there is no error:

```py
with open('file.png', 'wb') as pic:
  pic.write(img.getvalue())
```

Any advice on how I could achieve it without saving the file on the disk ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without saving to the disk. Before that, the error occurred in line

```
data=open(img.getvalue()).read()
```

Since the inbuild string operation is not good with different encodings this error occured.
use the [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) library to meddle with image realated situations

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image    
img = BytesIO(resp.content)
-#data=open(img).read()
+data = Image.open(img)
```

this will give you a following object type

```
<class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
```

you can use this data variable as your data in the upload post request

Comment: How would this be solved if the file was a PDF instead of an image?

Comment: @rafi you can use a method like this
pdf_file = StringIO(r.content)
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file) 
for PdfFileReader install PyPDF2 by pip install PyPDF2

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the embedded null byte error is caused by a filename input requirement of a library that is supporting whatever operation is being executed in your code. By using a `BytesIO` object this presents itself to that library "as if" it is wrapped inside a file.

Here is sample code that I used when trying to address this same issue with a tar file. This code should be able to satisfy most file input requirements for various other libraries.

The key that I found here was using the `BytesIO` object around the `remote_file.content` being passed into the `tarfile.open` as a file object. Other techniques I attempted did not work.

```
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import tarfile

remote_file=requests.get ('https://download.site.com/files/file.tar.gz')

#Extract tarball contents to memory
tar=tarfile.open(fileobj=BytesIO(remote_file.content))
#Optionally print all folders / files within the tarball
print(tar.getnames())
tar.extractall('/home/users/Documents/target_directory/')
```

This eliminated the `ValueError: embedded null byte` and `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO` errors that I was experiencing with other methods.

Answer (score 1):

@AmilaMGunawardana Thanks for the pointer.

I just had to save the image into a separate byte stream to get it uploaded properly:

```py
img = BytesIO(resp.content)

data = Image.open(img, 'r')

buf = BytesIO()

data.save(buf, 'PNG')

r = requests.post(url=url, data=buf.getvalue(), headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'user'))
```

Comment: Thats good but if you look into memory management use img variable to store the empty byte stream it will help towards speed and memory.